# Can't Access Port number 80 and 443 after adding Iptables rules

Tags: linux, tcp, centos, iptables

In my CentOS 6 i added a IPtables rules like DROP all the policy like

> iptables -P INPUT DROP

Then I allow Port NO 22,80,443 with this command,

> iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
>
> iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
>
> iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

Now can access SSH with putty. But i can't access Internet. I have to know the exact problem of this.? Please help me.

Comment: The rules look fine so far. We cannot say more with the little information you gave. Is the http server running at all? Does it work if you purge the rules completely again?

Comment: Only these rules? No ESTABLISHED one nor DNS accept?

Comment: Off topic. Try serverfault or superuser.

Answer (score 2):

*Ofcourse* you cannot access the Internet. You just added a rule that drops all incoming traffic (except for traffic coming in to ports 22, 80 and 443).

When you try to access the internet (if you're using a browser), your machine establishes a connection from

```
<local IP>:<port1>  <---->  <remote IP>:80
```

When the remote server responds to you, it will respond back to the same port1 that you sent the request from (which will NOT be 22, or 80, or 443. It will be a number usually higher than 32768), so it will get dropped by iptables.

Try these rules instead:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

The second rule tells IP tables to ACCEPT traffic that is coming to us, if it's coming to a port that we used to send outgoing traffic. This will allow you to see the response from the server, which you were dropping.

However, there's still a problem with DNS traffic, since it uses UDP not TCP. You can work around that by changing the first rule to:

```
iptables -P INPUT -p tcp DROP
```

so it only drops TCP traffic but not UDP traffic. There may be other ways to work around the DNS problem, depending on what exactly you want to do.

So your final ruleset should look like this:

```
iptables -P INPUT -p tcp DROP
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```